# ¿Porque no me actualiza la busqueda de una tabla? GORM en Go

Tags: go

estoy empezando con Go o Golang, el punto es que estoy haciendo un proyecto propio que es básicamente un crud para practicar, estoy usando GORM y todo bien, hace conexión, sirven las rutas, el problema radica en lo importante que es obtener los datos de la tabla de MySQL, estoy partiendo todo de la documentación y hasta ahorita ha funcionado, pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en efecto mi tabla no se llama alumnos, sino que es alumno, pero en el código eso ya lo marco

este es el código de mi main.go

```
package main

import (
 "net/http"
 "github.com/gorilla/mux"
 "github.com/NotAUserName0/crud/routes"
 "github.com/NotAUserName0/crud/controllers")

func main() {
  r :=mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("/", controllers.ShowUsers)
  http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080",r)
}
```

Ahora la carpeta controllers solo tiene un archivo llamado alumno_controller.go y tiene lo siguiente

```
import (
  "encoding/json"
  "net/http"
  "github.com/NotAUserName0/crud/databases"
  "github.com/NotAUserName0/crud/models")

 func ShowUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   alumnas := []models.Alumno{}
   db := databases.ConexionDB()
   defer db.Close()
   db.Find(&alumnas)
   json, _ := json.Marshal(alumnas)
   databases.SendResponse(w, http.StatusOK, json)
}
```

Ahora, partiendo de la documentación de GORM menciona que para hacer un 'select * from alumno' es usar db.Find(&variable), pero aunque está correcto no lo cambia a la hora de ejecutarlo, por ejemplo aquí lo pegue con el nombre 'alumna' pero si lo ejecutas sigue dando el error como alumnos, lo que me da a entender que la ejecución la hace mal y después da cambiar nombre de variables y eh incluso de la bd sigue igual, como puedo hacer que a la hora de ejecutar lea correctamente el archivo

A esto me refiero
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si se ocupa, pero este es mi model

```
package models

type Alumno struct {
   gorm.Model

   ID int64 `json:"id"`
   Nombre string `json:"nombre"`
   Grado int64 `json:"grado"`
}
```

¡Gracias!

Comment: puede ser que por defecto las tablas te las busque en plural. El ORM esperará que las tablas ya estén creadas. Al tu crear un struct con nombre singular, el te buscará la tabla como plural (tiene sentido). Esto por un lado.

Comment: Es justo lo que te comentaba, por defecto pluraliza tu struct para el nombre de la tabla: https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Conventions